# Using grpc in Laravel, "Class 'Grpc\ChannelCredentials' not found."

Tags: php, laravel, grpc

I am trying to use grpc in a Laravel project.

This is a part of my composer.json file:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "datto/protobuf-php": "dev-master",
    "google/auth": "^0.7.0",
    "grpc/grpc": "dev-release-0_13",
    ...
}
```

I have generated a php file from my proto file. It is placed in app/services/ and included in the composer.json `autoload.files` section. I have run `composer install` without issues.

I have created a route for testing. It has the following code:

```
$client = new vat_service\VatServiceClient('localhost:50051', [
    'credentials' => Grpc\ChannelCredentials::createInsecure()
]);
```

But I receive the response `Class 'Grpc\ChannelCredentials' not found.` when I visit the route.

The Laravel app is running in a Homestead vagrant box.

I don't know how to proceed. Am I missing a dependency? Did I miss to install something?

Comment: Did you try `\Grpc\ChannelCredentials` too?

Comment: Also check your vendor folder if the particular module is there.

Comment: I tried \Grpc\ChannelCredentials now Sugato, still getting the same error.

Comment: There is a grpc folder in the vendor folder. When I do a search for "ChannelCredentials" I find nothing except my own code line though.

Comment: Huh then that's the problem. If you use netbeans, you can do "use \Grpc\" and press ctrl + spacebar to see the available classes.

Comment: try running `composer update` once. I suspect that you got the wrong package though.

Comment: I have now tried composer update, nothing changed.

Comment: Just checked out their repo. It seems that you will need to have phpize, pecl, phpunit in order to use it. It also seems that ChannelCredentials is from pecl or something, but I honestly have no idea as I have never used it.

Comment: Hi Sugato, thanks for looking into this. phpize, pecl and phpunit are all installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem, but I am not sure which of the below steps was the solution.

Things I tried:

- I installed grpc-beta in the Homestead box (`sudo pecl install grpc-beta`).
- I updated from `"grpc/grpc": "dev-release-0_13"` to `"grpc/grpc": "^0.15.0"`.
- I added a repository to `composer.json`:

  ```
  "repositories": [
      {
          "type": "vcs",
          "url": "https://github.com/stanley-cheung/Protobuf-PHP"
      }
  ],
  ```
- I restarted NGINX inside the Homestead box
- I updated composer with `composer self-update`

I added this as an answer. Please advise if it would be better suited as an edit to the opening question or as a comment.

Also, it would be interesting to learn what the solution was.

Comment: This fine morning I encountered the problem again. My Homestead box was aborted, and on startup the problem was back again. This time I solved it quicker. The solution seems to be to add `extension=grpc.so` to the php.ini file for php-fpm. Then I restarted php-fpm and voilà, problem solved.

Comment: any news on this? after my ubuntu update some packages I got same error (but it used to work)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue but the above solution didn't work for me. My problem was that the `grpc\grpc` PHP package in composer and the grpc.so library were not the same version. I had 1.15 of the PHP package and 1.16 of the library.

You can install specific versions of the library with the following command:

```
sudo pecl install grpc-1.15.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This is day 2 I've been working on the OP's issue and you're the first to mention version incongruity.

Comment: This is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- composer update
- Replace vat_service\VatServiceClient to
  \vat_service\VatServiceClient

If not help, read here 
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/release-0_14/examples/php

If this does not help.Write in the comments.Let us try to something else

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking into this. Your suggestions sadly does no difference.

Comment: Read more carefully.
I can not tell you more than is written here  http://www.grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/php.html