# Using grpc in Symfony 4.1, “Class 'Grpc\ChannelCredentials' not found.”

Tags: php, symfony, grpc

After setting everything up to use grpc, according to the grpc documentation for php "https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/php.html", I tried to construct a client object from the classes I got from compiling some proto files with the proto compiler.

```php
$rezept_nameservice_client = new Rezept_NameserviceClient('localhost:8082',
        [ 'credentials' => Grpc\ChannelCredentials::createInsecure()]);
```

When I try to run my code, I get the following exception:

> Attempted to load class "ChannelCredentials" from namespace "App\Controller\Grpc".
>       Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Working enviroment:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Phpstorm
- Symfony 4.1
- Nginx 1.14.0
- grpc v1.15.0
- protobuf v3.6.1

I already tried different things to solve the problem which I found here:

[This Problem is the closest to the problem I have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185416/using-grpc-in-laravel-class-grpc-channelcredentials-not-found)

Comment: You need a leading backslash, \Grpc\ChannelCredentials::createInsecure()

Comment: I added a leading backslash, but the problem is the same

Comment: Hmmm.  Seems a bit unlikely.  Have you worked through the examples in the docs you linked outside of Symfony?  There seems to be quite a few installation steps to follow and I imagine it would be easy to skip one.  All I can suggest is to start fresh and get the example to work before trying to use inside of Symfony.

Comment: I installed everything clean on a new vm with the same working enviroment as in the problem description and for some reason it worked. I build it from source with the c library, like in gprc documentation and the "make" command was working much longer than before, when it doesnt worked.

Answer (score 0):

[Official documentation on installation for php](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/php/)

You need to install the `grpc.so` and `protobuf.so` extensions in the php.ini. My problem was I installed in the `fpm` php.ini, but forgot the `cli` php.ini and this is why I was having problems.

This specific class (`Grpc\ChannelCredentials`) does not exist anywhere in any PHP files. it comes from the C extension. To install these extensions, run:

```
sudo pecl install grpc
sudo pecl install protobuf
```

and add the this to your php.ini

```
extension=grpc.so
extension=protobuf.so
```

You can find the php.ini location by doing:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

**note if you're using `php-fpm`:**

Using `php -i | grep php.ini` will show you the `php.ini` for the command-line `php` command. The "php" that serves pages has its own `php.ini` usually somewhere close to the cli one. for example:

```
/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

The information to solve the problem is in the error message :

```
Attempted to load class "ChannelCredentials" from namespace "App\Controller\Grpc". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

I suppose you load this code from a specific class from the `App\Controller` namespace. and, they is no namespace `Grpc` in this namespace.

```php
$rezept_nameservice_client = new Rezept_NameserviceClient('localhost:8082',
        [ 'credentials' => Grpc\ChannelCredentials::createInsecure()]);
```

Firstly, I think the Namespace link the `Grcp\ChannelCredentials` class in the namespace is probably wrong to the `using` statements: the credentials can't be load, and that trow the error.

Check the namespace of the `\Grpc\ChannelCredentials` class defined to the place who use this code.

In second place, This error message explain the problem : this class can't be load and  `gRPC` is a php extension : you must to add `extension=grpc.so` into your `php.ini` file before use it ;)

If you use composer to your project, I recommand to add this extension to the `require` like that :

```
  "require": {
    "grpc/grpc": "^1.25.*"
  }
```

When you try to install your dependencies (`composer install`), you will have a composer error message if the dependencie is not found from your PHP version.